# Control YouTube video embedded in html

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I have a page with a YouTube video embedded in html. I want to stop the video when it's closed using the YouTube API. I have included SWFObject (and jquery), but I'm not able to control the video using any of the described methods.

```
document.getElementById()
swfobject.registerObject('id', 'version')
```

How can I control a youtube video using the js api without embedding it through swfobject i.e. by hooking up to the existing  tag in the DOM?

Edit for clarification: The video is displayed in a lightbox that is opened by the user and closed by clicking outside it. I want the video to stop playing when the user closes this lightbox.

Comment: is the video loaded via ajax? how about simply removing/clearing the lightbox dom object if you want to "stop" it?

Comment: The video is present on the page when its loaded. I was hoping I could use the api if possible so I can later have the option to pause/resume the video if the user reopens the lightbox. Will the video behave correctly if I simply remove the <object> and reinsert it later?

Comment: removing <object> and appending later seems to work so I'm going for that solution unless the api can be persuaded to talk to the <object>

Comment: youtube (as most of the google stuff) has nice api docs. try searching there http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/youtube/overview.html

Comment: I have been looking through it, but I cannot seem to find anything on "attaching" swfobject to an <object> already in the DOM. The seem to just assume you embed using swfobject directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be a better way: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/01/introducing-javascript-player-api-for.html

embed as an iframe. you can still control it with javascript.

Comment: Link is dead and there's no archive.org backup of it.